# PhpStorm can't configure JSHint

Tags: phpstorm, jshint

[image]

Can't figure out how to change .jshintrc file to make JSHint see variables inside `window` object without adding 'window'.

**.jshintrc**

```
"boss": true,
"curly": true,
"eqeqeq": true,
"eqnull": true,
"expr": true,
"immed": true,
"noarg": true,
"undef": true,
"unused": true,
"node": true,

"evil": true,
"sub": true,
"esversion": 6,

"globals": {
    "window": true,
    "JSON": false,

    "jQuery": true,
    "define": false,
    "module": false,
    "noGlobal": true
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to set up JSHint to accept variables created in `window` object. Please see https://github.com/jshint/jshint/issues/2555#issuecomment-122302652 for possible workaround